# Android Back/Up button and preserving previous intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation

I'm sure im missing something about the back stack and how it works here or maybe I just need to add a few lines here but I'm just trying to get my back button functionality working.

Activity A makes an API request using an ID passed via an intent extra to populate it's fields (this is done in onCreate). Activity B is opened from Activity A, but upon going back to Activity A, there is no id in the intent so no request can be made.

How can I setup my navigation so that the intent to create Activity A is preserved when starting Activity B, and resent when pressing the back button? Any functionality close to this, if easier, would probably be fine as well.

As of right now, I'm not doing anything special when i start Activity A.
Here is how I setup my back button in Activity B (along with specifying the parent activity as Activity A inside my manifest):

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar5);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Make sure there is a back button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Thanks for any help ahead of time.

Where I attach my ID to the intent and start Activity A:

```
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(context, ViewObjActivity.class);
detailsIntent.putExtra("objId", objId);
context.startActivity(detailsIntent);
```

Where I retrieve my ID from the intent in Activity A's onCreate:

```
// Get data from extras
Intent detailsIntent = getIntent();
mObjID = detailsIntent.getIntExtra("objId", -1);
```

### THE FIX

After a little digging, I found that the default back button functionality isn't that great.  By overriding the handler with the following, I was able to avoid having to store the ID as no call to onCreate is made - The activity's previous state is already stored.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()== android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: is the id persistent? ie. it will be used for a long time or is it for one time use?

Comment: @sihao it's one time use. Activity A is a details view for an object from the backend

Comment: Please post relevant code which shows from where you are getting id and where are you setting it , etc.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari if it's not enough to say that the activity A is started with an intent (as all of them are), and one of the extras is an int extra called "id", then i will post code

Comment: I need to see how are you fetching the id which you pass - its declaration and initialization.

Comment: Activity A just needs to know the ID (retrieved from the intent extras) to make a request to the API to get the data for an object with that ID. This request is made in onCreate

Comment: @ShadabAnsari Updated my question with this code.

Comment: " upon going back to Activity A, there is no id in the intent " - In which method you are checking your id when you come back to ActivityA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider this option instead.

When the intent to change from **Activity A to B is activated**, the onPause() method will be executed.

As such, the onPause() method will be a good place for you to save the state of your Activity.

```
public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCE = "";

 protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.clear();
    editor.putInt("ID", id);
    editor.commit();
}
```

You will have to recover your **SharedPreferences** **onResume()** and **onCreate()**.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like exactly what I need. Is onSavedInstanceState a method I can override from an AppCompatActivity? I'm not seeing it, but I am seeing onPostCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle), not sure if this is helpful though

Comment: Nevermind, it's called onSaveInstanceState without the 'd' ... thanks!

Comment: i suppose you can, you are suppose to override it from the Activity class. AppCompatActivity is a child of Activity.

Comment: Ok. So I overrode it, and I added code into onCreate for conditional assignment, but it seems like the instance state is not being saved. In onSaveInstanceState i write `state.putInt("objId", mObjId)` and then in onCreate I check if savedInstanceState is not null, then if it contains the correct key, and it's dropping into the else for that check when I go back to ActivityA.  Is there something extra that I have to do to actually save the state?  I start Activity B with a simple empty intent and call to startActivity.

Comment: sorry, i don't really catch this line " then if it contains the correct key, and it's dropping into the else for that check when I go back to ActivityA."

Comment: Sorry what I mean is that the check is falling and the flow of control drops into the else clause. The check is `if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("objID"))` ... Basically the savedInstanceState reference that is being passed into Activity A's onCreate, upon pressing the back button from Activity B, is null.

Comment: You can take a look at the tutorial here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html it shows how you can use it

Comment: Yep, I've done all of that.  Are you sure that the activity A state is automatically saved when calling `startActivity(this, activityB.class)` from activity A?

Comment: you can also try to add this method onRestoreInstanceState()

Comment: States are not automatically stored, only the method is triggered. You decide what is stored

Comment: Right, sorry, what I meant was whether or not that method was triggered .. it seems like it's not being called at all - going to look into this further

Comment: my apologies, i think i might have missed out a little. this method may not be triggered all the time. i will update my answer

Comment: looking into ways to trigger it... thanks for the help btw, I will certainly accept when I get this working

Comment: no probs. i have updated my answer. this should help better i hope

Comment: I've updated my answer with what fixed it.  Turns out I didn't even need to store the state at all since it's already done for us, the default back button functionality seems to be a little weird so I overrode it. I will accept this answer because it's entirely valid and you were very helpful